# Can I built a mobile application in which I can connect spring boot as backend REST API and codename as a frontend?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, codenameone, mobile-development

I am working on a master's project to design a mobile application using codename one. I am planning to use spring boot in the backend but don't know where to look for the examples. Can you help me how to establish a connection between codename one and spring boot project?

I tried searching several sites but there is not enough material available to guide how to implement this

Comment: Have you tried to use Google? There are thousands of thousands of tutorials of how to build Spring Boot Rest APIs. Maybe begin with one of Spring's own tutorials? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Answer (score 0):

There's a free course here that's slightly out of date but it includes examples of working with Spring Boot and Codename One to build full stack apps: https://debugagent.com/series/cn1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build a mobile application where the backend is a Spring Boot REST API and the frontend is developed using Codename One.